# Constructor return me None type instead of class type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a problem with python 3, classes and contructor. I've my class:

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self, store):
        self.store = store

    # other code
```

and when I create a object

```
menu = Menu(store)
```

the variable `menu` is None type, instead of being Menu type.
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Can't reproduce, the type is `<class '__main__.Menu'>`.

Comment: I'll venture a guess that `# other code` has something to do with this, or your testing is screwed up...

Comment: As it currently stands, your error can't be reproduced. Please provide all the necessary code you have to produce the error. If your code is too big, provide a minimal example that does produce it.

Answer (score 2):

Psychic debugging: Assuming you haven't replaced `Menu` somewhere else with something completely different, you defined a `__new__` on `Menu` in your `# other code`, and you failed to return a newly created object from `__new__`; thus, `__new__` returns `None`, and you don't actually construct anything.

Typically, you don't need both `__new__` and `__init__` on user defined classes in Python; just do all the initialization work in `__init__` and get rid of `__new__`.